# How to differentiate markers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers

I am working on Openstreet map. I have displayed markers in leaflet, but I want to design an interface and assign different groups to the markers. E.g. when an user clicks on "Hospitals", all the hospitals should be displayed on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You should study this [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html).

What you can do is group all your marker in the same category in a [L.LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup),
then the user will be able to add or remove it at will with the control.